# How can I find and replace text in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, find-and-replace

I have an online forum post in which I need to replace all instances of one word with another. (In Notepad++, this would be the Find and Replace option.)

**Is there a similar Find and Replace option for Google Chrome?**

[image: Notepad++ Find and Replace]

Comment: Type `data:text/html, <html contenteditable>` in browser and you can get notepad like editing.

Comment: @Biswapriyo could you explain - I think that just loads a non-secure blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Chrome is a web browser, not a word processor.

If you want "find and replace" functionality you'll have to add an extension to do it.

http://lifehacker.com/add-find-and-replace-functionality-to-your-browser-1640301419

Comment: I'm hoping that 'find and replace' could come in handy while drafting questions and answers for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan this find & replace extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-replace-for-text-edi/jajhdmnpiocpbpnlpejbgmpijgmoknnl?hl=en-US

In addition to your basic f&r functionality, it's got some other cool features built in.

Answer (score 0):

Find & Replace does not support some sites such as Wordpress, Magento, Confluence. You can use Search & Replace on most websites.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-replace-for-text-edi/jajhdmnpiocpbpnlpejbgmpijgmoknnl?hl=en-US

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).